# Javascript MySQL - TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of null

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, properties, typeerror

I'm trying to output the results from the selection query log into the console but I'm getting the following:

Code:

```
connection.query("SELECT userID FROM inventories WHERE ?", invCheckedIDres, function(result) {
  message.channel.send(result)
});
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of null
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:83:16)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\index.js:811:19)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:137:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:121:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\apixe\Documents\GS Bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which module are you using for your sql integration?

You're not logging it to the console, you're sending a message to discord. The query returns a row/rows[] object while  message.send also accepts a string, not rows. However I don't see in the code you provided where anything is accessing "embed" what line number is this code from?